Angular EventEmitter Not Triggering Parent Component Method
I'm having trouble with an EventEmitter in my Angular project. I have two components: absence-orders and action-box
Problem: The handleAddDoc method in the absence-orders component is not triggered when the addDocumentEvent is emitted. Other event emitters work fine.
Console Output:
"uploaddocs works" is logged, so I know the uploaddocs function is being called.
Maybe I'm missing a very little dumb detail. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?
<!-- absence-orders.component.html -->
<app-action-box 
  (addDocumentEvent)="handleAddDoc()" 
  (cancelEvent)="cancel(item?.id)" 
  (editEvent)="edit(item)">
</app-action-box>

// absence-orders.component.ts
  handleAddDoc() {
    console.log("handleAddDoc works");
  }

  cancel(itemId: string) {
    console.log("cancel works");
  }

  edit(item: any) {
    console.log("edit works");
  }






// action-box.component.ts
  @Output() editEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() cancelEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() approveEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() returnEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() rejectEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() detailEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() addDocumentEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  uploaddocs() {
    console.log("uploaddocs works");
    this.addDocumentEvent.emit();
  }



<!-- action-box.component.html -->
            <li (click)="uploaddocs()">
                <app-icon-node-plus class="icon icon--xs"></app-icon-node-plus>
                add document
            </li>


are you using event emitter from @angular/core ?

yes. all other eventEmitters work

please share stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens

Do post the answer so everyone knows the fix

It wasn't eventemitter related issue it's old project and some of the components have exact same names and structures and I messed up I was looking at another parent with same name
